# MySql server for Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I've just installed Visual Studio 2015 but I can't add the MySql server through data connection. All that appears is Microsoft SQL servers and Oracle, although I've installed MySql server and MySql server for Visual Studio.

So, what should I do?

Comment: What UI are you looking at?

Comment: Visual C# windows form application

Comment: Where in VS aren't you seeing MySQL?

Comment: Server explorer--->data connections--->add connection

Answer (score 1):

To connect to MySQL databases through the Server Explorer you must have the [MySQL Connector .NET](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) installed.

The MySQL Installer doesn't install the Connector for .NET by default.

Comment: After installing, did you restart Visual Studio? Remember MySQL Client, MySQL Server, and the MySQL _Connector_ (specifically the .NET one) are very different things.

Comment: In MySql installer i've installed: MySql server and MySql server for visual studio, what else can I do?

Comment: Install the .NET Connector that I've linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Download the MySQL connector. After installing it, you should see that is available.  I tend to just the MySQL Connector and code the connection to the server.  I can give you some code, if that is what you are looking for.